# Searching a list of words from textfile and printing first three lines using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file in that i have to access particular headings and access the first lines under the heading.I was able to do it for one heading while doing multiple heading i was facing issue.

I have successfully done for one heading. but doing to list of words i was unable to do it.
 i was able to do it for one heading
Data =['work:']

i was not able to do it for this scenario.
Data =['work:','test:','ride:']

```
In the text file the data is like below:
work:
'500'
'ast'
'800'

test:
'tim'
'200'
'300'

ride:
'mic'
'100'
'657'
```

```
import math
import os
import glob
import re
import sys



sys.path.append('C:/Documents/tes')



def read(file,Data,res,outputline):
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        stc_file = os.path.basename(file)
        for line in f:
            if Data in line:
                line = f.readlines()
                return line[outputline]

fls = []
src_dir = r'C:/Documents/tes'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
    for filename in files:
        if not filename.endswith('.txt'):
            continue
        filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
        fls.append(filepath)
        result = []
        Data = ['work:','test:','ride:']
        for file in fls:
            result=read(file,Data,result,0).split()+read(file,Data,result,1).split()+read(file,Data,result,2).split()
```

```
The above code is working for one heading,but for multiple headings i was not able to do.

['500','ast','800']
['tim','200','300']
['mic','100','657']
This above expected output .
```

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you are trying to do? It seems that you just want to read a text file, look for certain keyword/headings, append data from the following lines to an array, repeat. Is that correct?

Comment: yes i am trying to do same thing as you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will do what you asked, if each of the three (not sure if you wanted more, or an arbitrary number?) lines of data you are looking for are surrounded by single quotes—and if I understood your goal correctly...

```
import os

src_dir = os.getcwd()  # or whatever path you want
keywords = ['work:', 'test:', 'ride:']

result = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            try:
                fh = open(path, 'r')
                lines = [l.strip("'") for l in fh.read().splitlines()]

                for i in range(len(lines)):
                    if lines[i] in keywords:
                            result.append(' '.join(lines[i+1:i+4]).split())

            except Exception as e:
                print('Something went wrong.')
                print(e)
                continue

print(result)
```

Comment: I am a newbie to python.the above solution is working and thanks lot for the help.